# Need to move files from VM and put into storage explorer - Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage-explorer

Every day at 8am we have files generated inside a VM that only I can access. I want to get those files automatically uploaded to a storage account that everyone can access, after they have been generated. How is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You need to create a Windows Service or a job inside your VM

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

You can use PowerShell or bash script to move files from VM to a storage account.

Login to Azure Portal --> Go to your VM --> Under Settings, click on Identity --> Enable System Assigned Identity and click on save

[image]

Click on Azure role assignments --> Add Role Assignment --> Select scope as storage --> Select your storage account in the resource --> Select Storage Blob Data Contributor role --> Click on Save

Log in to your VM and install Azcopy : [Copy or move data to Azure Storage by using AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy)

If it is a windows VM, create the below as PowerShell script to copy files from VM to your storage account. If it is a Linux VM, create the below as a bash script :

```
azcopy login --identity

azcopy copy "path\to\folder\*" "https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/"
```

Create a scheduled task to execute the PowerShell to execute daily at a scheduled time to copy files from VM to your storage account for Windows VM : [How To Create a Scheduled Task in Windows 10 (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-scheduled-task-in-windows-10/)

For Linux VM, create a cronjob to run the bash script daily at a scheduled time : [How to Create and Run Cron Jobs on Linux - RoseHosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-create-and-run-cron-jobs-on-linux/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20crontab%20or%20edit%20an,use%20the%20new%20settings%20from%20the%20crontab%20file.)

[image]

[image]